# Swift 5 unable to map JSON object from API call

Tags: swift, swift5, jsondecoder

I have an API call that is returning a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{"took":19,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":1,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":11.1074705,"hits":[{"_index":"test_data","_type":"test_type","_id":"dAT6YHoB2mxCCW1k6TLU","_score":11.1074705,"_source":{"name": "mz1v60MiJ", "age": 41706, "last_updated": 1625601405000}}]}}
```

When I try to map it to an object, I get the following error:

```
Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil),
Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "hits", intValue: nil),
CodingKeys(stringValue: "hits", intValue: nil),
_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)],
debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"name\", intValue: nil) (\"name\").",
underlyingError: nil))
```

Here is the code for userViewModel.swift where I am calling the API:

```
class apiCall {
    func getUsers(completion:@escaping ([User]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.5:9200/_search?q=mz1v60MiJ") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let users = try! JSONDecoder().decode(UserResponse.self, from: data!)
            print(users)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(users.hits.hits)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

And this is the UserModel file for the object:

```
struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let last_updated: Date
}

struct UserHits: Codable {
    let hits: [User]
}

struct UserResponse: Codable {
    let hits: UserHits
}
```

The data I need is in the second "hits" of the JSON, but it doesn't seem to be able to find the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need a new type to use between UserHits and User

```
struct HitData: Codable {
    let source: User

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case source = "_source"
    }
}

struct UserHits: Codable {
    let hits: [HitData]
}
```

You also need to fix the User struct if you want to add the `id` property by giving the property a correct type

```
struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let lastUpdated: Date
}
```

and finally when decoding you should set a date decoding strategy so your date value gets correctly parsed (and use `convertFromSnakeCase` so you don't need _ in your property names when the json key has one)

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to have one more level of the nested json object for "_source" key